# Zend Framework: Model class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

The following exception is thrown on my server: 
**Fatal error: Class 'My_Model_Bo_User_Agenda_Doctors' not found in...** 
Though in localhost everything is working fine.

I checked that everything was correctly uploaded; all the files are present and not corrupted. I also tried to upload several times. So this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Any idea why a class couldn't be found on the server ?

Comment: Are there other classes that do get succesfully loaded with the same method?

Comment: Did you make sure that the path `My` is in was added to your `include_path`?  Even with the autoloader, if the parent directory of the `My` folder is not in path, it will not find the class.

Comment: @shokora yes, I do the following:
$doctorsModel = new My_Model_Doctors();
$doctorsMap = new My_Model_Bo_User_Agenda_Doctors();
it only fails for My_Model_Bo_User_Agenda_Doctors

Comment: @drew010 I included "My". It always used to work, I have a lot of other classes starting by "My_". require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace(array('My_', 'MyZend_'));
$resourceLoader  = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
 'namespace' => 'My',
 'basePath'  => './application/'
));

Comment: @Matthew  Ok, just checking.  What you have looks sound as long as `My` is located under `application/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say so in your question, but I suspect that you are developing on windows and hosting on Linux.

Windows is not case sensitive to path names, but Linux is! Check that:-

1. Doctors.php is *not* doctors.php
2. Agenda/ is *not* agenda/ .etc
3. Lastly check the class name in the class declaration is correct and correctly cased.

Do not just think to yourself, yes I've done that, go and check them carefully. Believe me, bitter experience has taught me this problem is always due to a trivial oversight like this.