# form element class is not loaded zf after uploading in dev server

Tags: zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework: Model class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167387/zend-framework-model-class-not-found)

I am using ZF 1.11 and made a form element class to create drop down menu on the form .  i get the error: Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_Element_MenuSelect' not found after uploading the application in development server while  It works perfectly in local xampp. Please help

```
    $project_menu1 = new Application_Form_Element_MenuSelect('task_project_id');
    $project_menu1->setLabel('Select Project: ')
    ->setRequired(true);
    $this->addElement($project_menu1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it worked on Windows and doesn't work on your dev server, I suspect that you have a case-sensitivity issue with filenames as your dev server will almost certainly need the case of the filename to be correct.

Things to check:

1. The file is called MenuSelect.php
2. The folder name to MenuSelect.php has the correct case (probably should be application/forms/Element)
3. The class name within MenuSelect.php is correct