# Zend Framework Migration to Live Server

Tags: zend-framework, lamp, mamp

Pardon me guys, I am new to ZF. I need to move my codes from MAMP production server to LAMP Live Server.

When I am working on localhost with the codes are all working fine. However when I upload it to live server, 60% of the modules reflect this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message
>   'script 'layout.phtml' not found in path
>   (/home/lifeoppc/public_html/application/layouts/:/home/lifeoppc/public_html/application/modules/default/views/scripts/:./views/scripts/)'
>   in /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/View/Abstract.php:988 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/View/Abstract.php(884):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->_script('layout.phtml') #1
>   /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Layout.php(796):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->render('layout.phtml') #2
>   /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php(143):
>   Zend_Layout->render() #3
>   /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php(333):
>   Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout->postDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
>    #4 /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Controller/Front.php(965): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
>    #5 /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(9
>   in /home/lifeoppc/public_html/public/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php
>   on line 336

I really really need help! Site is going live on Monday and I am really desperate right now =(

Comment: What do you have in your application.ini? Your viewPaths are probably not the same than the ones on your MAMP server.

Comment: Hi Liyali,

[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "LifeOpp_"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""

resources.layout.layoutpath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"

Comment: i point to the five different layouts using this code in each controller's init()

$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('employee-layout');

Comment: And where are `employee-layout.phtml` and `layout.phtml` in your directory structure?

Comment: it is housed under APPLICATION_PATH/layouts/employee-layout.phtml

Comment: Is `APPLICATION_PATH` correctly defined to `/home/lifeoppc/public_html/application/`?

Comment: yes, it is. I just find it weird as there are 18 modules on my project. 5 of the modules work fine with the same layout codes. 13 modules reflect the error stated above. However, on my local machine all 18 modules work well. I am using ZF 1.11 with php version 5.3.6 / 5.2.17 on my machine and ZF 1.11 with php version 5.2.17. Does the versioning affects the output of the project? But if thats the case it should be 100% not working and not only 5/18 working.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9174517/212940) help?

Comment: Oh my! THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!! Its the naming of the files that are screwing me up.

Answer (score 0):

Search for file `layout.phtml` inside your project and then copy paste it inside directory

```
/home/lifeoppc/public_html/application/layouts/
```

Comment: I have 5 diffent layouts. I called them via 

//SET THE LAYOUT
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('employee-layout');

this method works for Local host but it does not work on the Live Server.