# Controller file + View exists - still throws an error online [Zend Framework]

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have my zend framework application all set up - its working fine on my localhost, recently just deployed it to a staging server. For some strange reason one specific controller isn't working at all. Its throwing the following error:

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

The controller file and view files are all online, no spelling errors or case errors - all other controllers are working and their actions, however this one specific controller isn't working and none of its actions are. In-fact I have noticed that whatever action I try to call off this controller I get the error station that Action index doesn't exist? Whats going on here.

---

For instance here's my controller file:

```
class HolidaysController extends App_Controller_Action {
  public function indexAction() {

  }
}
```

Comment: This may be obvivious and a stupid question, but are you sure you have a public function indexAction() in the controller (spelled correctly), correct file name, correct namespace, correct directory (cant remember if zf1 uses namespaces or not)? Just want to mention it because heaven knows I have pounded my head against the wall a many of times for spending hours debugging stuff that was just as obvious and dumb

Comment: Which server you use? If you are using the linux server then you must check the naming convention of the `class` and `function` the same problem i am face in the past i have problem in naming convetion. So please check it once

Comment: What's the url triggering the error? Any custom routes in place?

Comment: If your localhost is windows [this answer may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9174517/212940).

Comment: shouldn't `App_Controller_Action` be `Zend_Controller_Action` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By any chance are you developing on a Mac or Windows machine, and deploying to a Linux server?  I get tripped up like this sometimes because the standard filesystem on my Mac is *not* case sensitive, but it is on my Linux servers.  So if I mess up in how I capitalize my controller file names, it can go undetected until I deploy to my servers.

If you think this might be the problem, log into your server (SSH or FTP) and check the capitalization of that controller's filename.  If that's the issue, it can be a little tricky to fix because if you rename the file on Mac or Windows, the new capitalization doesn't necessarily get picked up when committed to a source control repository and/or uploaded to the server.  The trick is to first rename the file to something else, then rename it back with exactly the capitalization you need.

Comment: I realized this wouldn't be the problem, otherwise ZF would indicate a missing controller rather than a missing action.  Anyway, I am leaving my answer here because it seems helpful to people.